# keep looping a function until the callback inside resolves to true

Tags: javascript, while-loop, async-await

I've the two interconnected functions.

```
module.exports = async function newRunner() {
  console.log('No Config found. Requesting new Runner ID');

  if (!process.env.ADDRESS) {
    const a = await inquirer.prompt([
      {
        type: 'input',
        message: 'Enter the runner api address',
        name: 'address',
      },
    ]);

    config.ADDRESS = a.address;
  } else {
    config.ADDRESS = process.env.ADDRESS;
  }

  config.save();

  const res = await auth.checkAddress();

  console.log('New Runner ID', res.id);

  config.ID = res.id;
  config.TOKEN = res.token;
  config.save();
};
```

The line `const res = await auth.newRunner();` call the following function.

```
exports.checkAddress = args => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const cArgs = {
    data: args,
    path: {},
    parameters: {},
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };

  client.post(`${config.ADDRESS}/new-runner`, cArgs, (data, response) => {
    if (response.statusCode !== 200) return reject(new Error(`Status code ${response.statusCode}`));
    return resolve(data);
  })
    .on('responseTimeout', (res) => {
      console.log('Update Response Timeout!', res);
      reject(new Error('response has expired'));
    })
    .on('error', (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
});
```

I need to keep the first function running until the address entered is correct and the second function resolves to true. I've tried the following.

```
 await newRunner();
    while (!await auth.newRunner()) {
      await newRunner();
    }
```

The functions runs as it should if I enter the correct address, wrong address breaks it, but I want it to keep looping until the address is correct. What do I need to change do archive the correct behaviour?

Comment: It's **really awkward** to answer this question when the functions have the same name. (Seems like it would be awkward to maintain, too.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm aware, but the code was designed this way when I joined, I might try to refactor it later. For now I just want to get them to function.

Comment: It's just, for next time, it may be worth giving them different names in the question, just for clarity. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "main" `newRunner` (at the top of your question) only fulfills when `auth.newRunner` fulfills, and rejects otherwise. `auth.newRunner` only fulfills when it successfully got data. So to loop until you've successfully got data, you need to wrap the call in a `try`/`catch`:

```
let failed;
do {
    try {
        await newRunner();
        failed = false;
    } catch {
        failed = true;
    }
} while (failed);
```

Might be best to put some limits on that, though, so it can't cycle infinitely.

Comment: Hm, `failed = await newRunner().then(() => false, () => true)`?